# Sort Query Pivot Table - Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-query-language

I am trying to sort a query pivot table in order that the columns should be in descending order.

I tried:`=QUERY({Data!A1:C24},"Select Col1, Sum(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3 order by Col1 Desc, Col2 Desc")` but it tells me that `"COL_IN_ORDER_MUST_BE_IN_SELECT: Col2"`.

Is there a way to sort the columns of the pivot table in addition to the rows?

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8T2BJvSRN_CMdTs1asONEWrDjT3c5yDTFRxh8mSh10/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Data!A1:C24},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2)
  group by Col1
  pivot Col3
  order by Col1 desc")), 
 "order by Col1 desc", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Amazing, can't believe there isn't a less convoluted way to do this

Answer (score 0):

By the way...
If you turn your original desired pivot round first you should be able to achieve the same result with just one transpose

```sql
=QUERY(
  TRANSPOSE(
    QUERY(
      {Data ! A1 : C24}, "select Col3,sum(Col2) 
    group by Col3 pivot Col1 
    order by Col3 desc"
    )
  ), 
  "order by Col1 desc", 
  1
)
```