# Query/Pivot Function: Header Title Descending Order & Month Format mmmm yyyy

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**[Goal]**
I want to create a table with the Query Function where it counts the number of 'Drivers' for each month in a dynamic manner. Meaning that when the data (example sheet is called 'Data') is updated, it'll be updated automatically as well.

**[What I was able to do so far]**
I was able to create a table with the Query Function, however, it only displays 1 column worth of Months when I want to show up to 4 months. And I also want to show the recent months from the left and the older months on the right.

**[Formula that I have so far]**

```
=QUERY(Data!$A:$B,"
SELECT B,
Count(B) 
Where B != '' AND MONTH(A)=MONTH(DATE'"&TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')
Group By B 
Pivot A
Order By B asc
Label B 'Drivers', Count(B) '"&TEXT(A2,"MMMM YYYY")&"'",1)
```

**[Issue that I'm facing]**
I've tried specifying the date range like the below, however there are 2 problems.

1. The date format is not mmmm yyyy (Example: May 2022) and it'd show as: 2022-2-1 May 2022
2. The months are ordered in an ascending manner (Example: 2022-2-1, 2022-3-1, 2022-4-1) instead of descending (Example: 2022-4-1, 2022-3-1, 2022-2-1)

So I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this. Hopefully I can have support.

```
Where B != '' AND MONTH(A)<=MONTH(DATE'"&TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')
AND MONTH(A)>=MONTH(DATE'"&TEXT(EDATE(A2,-3),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')
```

[image]

**[Sample Sheet]**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AJYTRga9-dXbj64nl4RfpDKs5JYSFwP2SiR7v7gAhMI/edit#gid=1297239620

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the date format in a Google Sheets query pivot table with date filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890839/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-in-a-google-sheets-query-pivot-table-with-date-f)

Comment: @idfurw This will work for date format changing but won't work for descending order. Seems pivot always sort header in ascending order.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
QUERY({Data!A:B, TEXT(Data!A:A, "yyyymmdd×MMMM yyyy")}, 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 != ''
    AND MONTH(Col1)<=MONTH(DATE'"&TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')
    AND MONTH(Col1)>=MONTH(DATE'"&TEXT(EDATE(A2,-3),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col3", 1)),"order by Col1 desc")),"^(.*×)", ))
```

Reference:

[How do I change the date format in a Google Sheets query pivot table with date filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69891266/16125139)

[Sort Query Pivot Table - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768523/16125139)

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving my issue and I'm sorry I wasn't able to resolve it with the shared references. This is really great.

Comment: Though I have one question. Thanks to you, I was able to create the dynamic table based on the data, however, it shows "No data" when using the table to create a chart. Is there a way to create a chart with this...? You can see that the chat isn't working in the example sheet that I have shared in the question.

Comment: The reason is that the number fields are converted into string. I do not have a good method but to simply create the header and body separately and then merge them together. (which you could do in a loooong formula)

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much for your help. This was a great learning experience, thanks to you.